# Как понять, почему не создается каталог?

Tags: java

Есть метод, который с моей точки зрения должен создавать каталоги:

```
private void createCatalogs() {
        File debugCatalog = new File(pathToDebug); // например pathToDebug = "D:\\debug\\2017_10_23"
        if (!debugCatalog.exists()) { //если каталога нет
            debugCatalog.mkdirs(); // создадим каталог
        }                
    }
```

После выполнения этого метода каталог не создается, исключений не выбрасывается. Что я делаю не так?

**UPD**
создал второй метод

```
private void createCatalogs2() {
        File debugCatalog = new File(pathToDebug); // например pathToDebug = "D:\\debug\\2017_10_23"
        if (!debugCatalog.exists()) { //если каталога нет
            java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories( debugCatalog.toPath()); // создадим каталог
        }                
    }
```

Теперь у меня есть исключение, но причина ошибки по прежнему не понятна:

> Unable to determine if root directory exists

Comment: *Returns: true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise* - проверяйте что вам возвращает метод

Comment: `Unable to determine if root directory exists` странная ошибка. Не могу понять, что ее вызывает

Comment: Вставлю свои 5 копеек: проверьте права на запись в место, где хотите создать каталог.

Comment: В том и дело, что все права есть. Более того, ранее этот код создавал каталоги. Я понимаю, что магии не бывает, но вроде как ничего и не менялось даже.

Comment: 1. где именно вылетает? судя по тому что во втором варианте, уже на этапе создания... кароче, stack trace в студию :)
2. что значит "ничего не менялось", версия jvm и параметры запуска тоже не поменялись?
3. как инициализируется pathToDebug? что то мне не нравятся обратные слэши.

Comment: вылетает на `createDirectory`. Запускаю из IDEA. Версия JVM не менялась. Параметры запуска не менялись. `pathToDebug` инициализируется именно так, как написано в комментариях

Comment: Ну тут надо проверить существует ли диск "D" например. Может буква другая?